# Clarification on C++ constructor syntax

Tags: c++, syntax

I am curious as to whether any clarification can be provided on the multitudes of constructor syntax's there are in C++. I have seen constructors declared inside of classes, and outside of classes. I have also seen variable initialization through more common methods such as `x = y` or `this-> x = y`, but also through initialization lists, like `Point(int i = 0):x(i) {}`.

My question is whether there are certain situations where it is more suitable to use one style of constructor over another, or whether to declare the constructor inside or outside the class. Is their some commonly followed syntax guideline for this?

Comment: My advice, **always** use the member initialization syntax, i.e: `Point(int i = 0):x(i) {}`

Comment: Constructors are always a part of the class (so it is always inside the class). Now if you provide a seprate declaration in the class then implement the definition in another file that simply depends on what is easier to read (simple inline in the class, complex in  a seprate file).

Answer (score -1):

I feel it is generally a good idea to have constructors' destructors and other methods' prototypes inside the class itself, if they belong to the same class. It is more efficient and more programmer friendly.
for eg:
I would do something like this:

```
class decl ....{
    private:
        members var.. methods' prototype..
    public:
        decl();  default cons prototype
        decl(type para....); parameterized cons prototype;
        ~decl();
        some methods' prototypes..
    };
```

Then you can always go ahead and use them take an argument to assign the value to instant variable
such as this:

```
decl::decl(can user the same name or different ){

    if using the same name 
    this -> sameName = sameName;

    otherwise,
    instant data variable name = assign the value,
    }
```

Comment: I consider myself an expert in C++ but... I don't really understand what you're trying to communicate here